# Flask generating requests with random port

Tags: python, flask

Am trying to generate a get request from a flask server to another, on destination side when I print the port, I keep getting random ports with each request

CLIENT:

```
    from flask import Flask, redirect, request
    import requests
    app = Flask(__name__)
    @app.route('/acqlock/<resource_name>')
    def acquire_resource(resource_name):
        print request.url
        response = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8080/acqlock/' + resource_name)
        return response.text
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="localhost", port=8081)
```

SERVER :

```
    from flask import Flask, redirect, request

    app = Flask(__name__)
    @app.route('/')
    @app.route('/acqlock/<resource_name>')
    def acquire_lock(resource_name):
        print request.url
        print request.environ.get('REMOTE_PORT')
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=int("8080"))
```

it keeps printing http://127.0.0.1:8080/acqlock/file 58077 eventhough I was expecting it to print http://127.0.0.1:8081  8081 as the server is generating the request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is *normal*. Remember that `requests` is the client here, it has to create a *new* HTTP connection to another server. TCP connections *on the client side* need a port as well, and when you create a socket to a remote server you are assigned a port number by the OS for the client-side of the connection.

That you are making this outgoing HTTP connection in the context of an incoming HTTP connection is neither here nor there. It is a *different* connection, in a different direction.

If you need to identify where the request came from, add information to the request. You can add custom headers, a cookie, query parameters, or post data.

Comment: is there a way to fix the port ? or even generate the request using flask app currently running ?

Comment: Why do you think you need this? No, you can't.

Comment: I have 2 other clients generating the requests, I want to tell them apart at the server to do something like  (client, no of requests made) history

Comment: @fadytaher: then add a cookie, or a query parameter, or a header. Using client port numbers is not the way distinguish between requests here.

Comment: can do that, but I think those can be faked, I need something to ascertain the url caller

Comment: @fadytaher: Then give them something cryptographically signed to send along in a cookie or header. API authentication is a solved problem.